# Value for initialized int is different when empty string initialized

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
int main()
{
    int local_int;
    std::cout << local_int << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which prints `0`.

But the next function:

```
int main()
{
    int local_int;
    std::string local_str;
    std::cout << local_int << std::endl;
    std::cout << local_str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
21930
```

(the second line is the empty string)

Can someone help me understand what is going on between the two functions and why local_int isn't zero in the second function?

Comment: You claim that `local_int` is initialized, but it's not. The behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title mentions an initialised int, but it really is not.

The declaration `int local_int;` (where you have it<sup>(1)</sup> in the source code) declares an *uninitialised* integer which may have *any* arbitrary value, it's as legal for it the be `314159` as it is to be zero.

If you *want* it to have a specific value, simply initialise it with something like:

```cpp
int local_int = 42;
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This is because it is *automatic storage duration*. If it had a *different* storage duration, it would follow different rules and may be default- or zero-initialised. But that is not the case with this simple non-`static` `int` declaration within a function.

More information on the different storage durations, and how they are initialised (or *not*), are covered in the ISO C++ standard in excruciating detail :-)